# PowerShell script doesn't return the correct answer to Test-Path

Tags: powershell

I've created the below PowerShell script to check if the "D:\Apps" folder exists on a list of servers (C:\Healthcheck\Servers.txt).

```
$Computers = Get-Content C:\Healthcheck\Servers.txt

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $TestPath = Test-Path \\\$computers\D$\Apps

    if ($TestPath -eq 'True') {
        Write-Host "The Apps folder exists on $computer"
    } else {
        Write-Host "The Apps folder doesn't exist on $computer"
    }
}
```

I've created the "D:\Apps" folder on a server but the script says it doesn't exist:

> The Apps folder doesn't exist on ServerName

If I run the command locally on the server it finds the "D:\Apps" folder:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Test-Path D:\Apps
True
```

Am I missing something? I can query the server remotely using PowerShell to check if a service is running so there's no access problems.

Comment: Problem could be due to folder not being shared or your permissions. Think about using `Invoke-command` to see what happens.

Comment: `\\\$computers` -> `\\$computer`

Comment: I've fixed it. The variable needed to be "$computer" not "$computers" the Tes-Path command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo in

```
    $TestPath = Test-Path \\\$computers\D$\Apps
```

Try

```
    $TestPath = Test-Path \\$computer\D$\Apps
```

Comment: `\\$computer\D:\Apps` is not a valid UNC path.